# MS Failover Clustering Key - 4f692a7dc1b824e1f679f93fadd08a3b

Tags: keys

4f692a7dc1b824e1f679f93fadd08a3b seems to be a common identifier for a RSA key associated with MS Failover clustering.  It doesn't seem to be affiliated to the certificate ClusInfraCert, but rather some other service of clustering.  We've accidentally deleted it from C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys.  I think I should be able to export the certificate and private key from another member of the cluster, and import it on the failed node, but I can't find the certificate anywhere in the Certificates Snap-In (I've looked in the service certificate view for ClusSvc, and SMB Witness).  Does anyone know more details about this, or know of a way to reverse which certificate is associated with a particular key file?

Comment: Note that a quick look didn't show any mention of this key ID in Google which means it is probably **not** "common". Usually key ID's are hashes of the modulus, and are therefore unique.

Comment: Thanks Maarten,  I was only able to find a few references to the key id in a few cluster forums if I searched those sites directly, but Google didn't seem to index it.  In a disposable cluster I built, I did determine that if I evict the node with the missing key, and add the node back, this will put the key back on the server (without me having to export/import manually).  Now I just need to determine with MS if this is a supported method for an MS Exchange DAG cluster, since Exchange manages the cluster somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a way to export and import this key, but evicting the cluster node and adding it back to the node re-added the key to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys in the lab.  Since production was an Exchange DAG, removing the server from the DAG and adding it back, and letting Exchange take care of the cluster evict and re-add actions fixed the issue.